# Cannot import module that imports a custom class

Tags: python, import, module, path, scope

I have a directory and module design that looks like this:

```
MyProject --- - script.py
             |
              - helpers --- - __init__.py
                           |
                            - class_container.py
                           |
                            - helper.py
```

```
# class_container.py

class MyClass:
    pass
```

```
# helper.py

from class_container import MyClass
def func():
   # some code using MyClass
```

```
# script.py

from helpers.helper import func
```

When I run `script.py`:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'class_container'
```

I tried changing the code in `helper.py` such as:

```
# helper.py

from helpers.class_container import MyClass
def func():
   # some code using MyClass
```

Then running `script.py` started working. But when I explicitly run `helper.py`:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'
```

I want to be able run both `script.py` and `helper.py` separately without needing to change the code in any module.

---

**Edit:** I figured a solution which is changing `helper.py` such as:

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys

sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parent))

from class_container import MyClass
def func():
   # some code using MyClass
```

Basically I added the directory of `helper.py` to `sys.path` by using `sys` and `pathlib` modules and `__file__` object. And unlike `import` statement's behaviour, `__file__` will not forget it's roots when imported/used from a different module (i.e it won't become the path of `script.py` when imported into it. It'll always be the path of `helper.py` since it was initiated there.).

Though I'd appreciate if someone can show another way that doesn't involve messing with `sys.path`, it feels like an illegal, 'unpythonic' tool.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'class_container.py'` Are you sure that is the exact error message?  There shouldn't be a `.py` at the end.

Comment: @JohnGordon You are right. I fixed it. The actual name isn't class_container so I made a typo while changing the name

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path - it seems you are lacking an `__init__.py` file in `helpers`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 There was already a `__init__.py` in `helpers`. I added it to the post. It's not the solution unfortunately. The question still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a `__init__.py` file in the `MyProject/helpers` directory. Maybe you already have created it. If not, create an empty file.

Then in the `MyProject/helpers/helper.py`, access the module `helpers.class_container` like this.

```
from helpers.class_container import MyClass
def func():
   # some code using MyClass
```

You can also use a relative import like this.

```
from .class_container import MyClass
```

If you want to run the `MyProject/helpers/helper.py` independently, add test code in `helper.py` like this.

```
from helpers.class_container import MyClass
def func():
   # some code using MyClass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func()
```

And run like this in the `MyProject` directory.(I assume a Linux environment.)

```
$ python3 -m helpers.helper
```

The point is to differentiate Python modules from Python scripts and  treat them differently.

Comment: I already have the `__init__.py` in `MyProject/helpers`. I had already stated that I tried your solution in my post. I said that this only works when I run `script.py`. I also want this to work when I explicitly run `helpers.py`

Comment: I added a solution to that case.

Comment: Strange that it worked: `$ python3 -m helpers.helper`. It assigns `__name__` to `'__main__'` but still loads it as a module such that the relative import statement `from .class_container import MyClass` in `helper.py` runs without error.

Comment: It's the standard way to run a module. See [PEP 338](https://peps.python.org/pep-0338/).